# Lambdas and only 1 argument in case statements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, lambda

As I get it, you can use a proc/lambda inside, switch, for example:

```
is_even = ->(x) { x % 2 == 0 }

case number
when 0 then puts 'zero'
when is_even then puts 'even'
else puts 'odd'
end
```

As I understand it, and from the examples I see, is it that lambdas can be used in case statements ONLY IF they accept only 1 parameter, since you can't do a case statement with more than 1 argument (case a, b isn't possible, except if maybe these elements are enclosed into an array). So basically if you try to use a lambda with more than 1 parameter in a case statement the code is going to break. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Basically you're right, but what's the use case?

Comment: You could always use an Array, or Hash as your single param. A custom class (or extension of existing class to cover the needed cases) is also possible, but in that case you would probably implement some instance methods for the tests, rather than make use of lambdas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because:

```
is_even = ->(x) { x % 2 == 0 }
is_even.lambda? #true
```

is "lambda" ( `is_even = lambda(x) { x % 2 == 0 }` is equivalent of above code)

There exist `proc`s:

```
is_even = proc{|x| x % 2 == 0 } # Proc.new{|x| x % 2 == 0 }
is_even.lambda? #false
```

`lambda`s checks for number of arguments. `proc`s on other hand doesn't check number of arguments.

```
ppp1 = Proc.new{|x| x % 2 == 0 } #=> #<Proc:0x507f300@(pry):152>
ppp1.call(2,3,4,5) #true

ppp2 = ->(x){ x % 2 == 0 } # => #<Proc:0x2c5ac40@(pry):158 (lambda)>
ppp2.(2,4) # ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

You can read more [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Proc.html#method-i-lambda-3F).